# Anguar - using ngModel in a dynamic list of checkboxes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a dynamic Angular material `mat-table` with a checkbox column. How can I provide an ngModel to these such that it is specific to each individual checkbox? Using `checked` applies to the checkbox in every row so checking one selects them all.

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="selectCheck">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked" (change)="checkSelected(row)"></mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

TS

```
  checked = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="row.checked" (change)="checkSelected(row)"></mat-checkbox>
```

You can set `checked` property for each row object to make it specific for each row of the table.

Using the `checked` of the component will occur selection of all check boxes.

Comment: If you could give me more details I would really help